# jQuery 1.4.2, get text and replace first character

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I have the following HTML:

```
<span class="drop_cap">3 <span>Dinners</span></span>
```

I want to replace that first character. The number will change depending on user interaction, so I can't just grab "3"

I've tried:

```
$("drop_cap").text().substr(0,1).replace(var);
```

and

```
$("drop_cap").html().substr(0,1).replace(var);
```

and similar things.

TIA

Comment: Start by reading the JS docs for `replace`

Comment: And understand the `replace` doesn't change a string in place, you have to assign the result of `replace` back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is not very good at dealing with text nodes. Since you know you want to edit the first node (text node) inside the span, you can do the following.

```
// This inserts 100 in front of that text node inside drop_cap
$("span.drop_cap").each(function(){
    this.firstChild.nodeValue = "100" + this.firstChild.nodeValue;
});
```

Here's an example that uses `String.replace`

```
$("span.drop_cap").each(function(i){
    this.firstChild.nodeValue = this.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/\d/, i);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rLGPW/2/, http://jsfiddle.net/rLGPW/3/

Comment: The string replace was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

work around, and this is easier especially if you are just using numbers:

```
<input id='number' type='text' readonly='readonly' value='3'>
```

NOW YOU CAN USE J-QUERY TO CHANGE THE VALUE OF THE INPUT, which is a ton less buggy than trying to change html.

```
$("#number").val(var);
```

and make sure you css the input box because by default it has funky input box style

Answer (score 0):

If you know there's always a number and then some text only, I guess you could use a simple regex to extract the number:

```
var num = $('span.drop_cap').text().match(/\d+/)[0]
```

Comment: OP is not looking to extract the number, they're looking to replace it